# conflicting types for 'main' in leetcode platform

Tags: c

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<stdlib.h>
int* twoSum(int* nums, int numsSize, int target) {
    int *a=(int *)malloc(2*sizeof(int));
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<numsSize;i++)
         for(j=i+1;j<numsSize;j++)
    if(nums[i]+nums[j]==target)
    {a[0]=i;a[1]=j;}
    return a;
}
void main(){
    int target,i;
    int numsSize;
    int b[2];
    int num[10];
    int *s;
    s=b;
    printf("Please input numsSize");
    scanf("%d",&numsSize);
    for(i=0;i<numsSize;i++)
    scanf("%d",&num[i]);
    printf("Please input target");
    scanf("%d",&target);

    s=twoSum(num,numsSize,target);
    printf("【%d,%d】",s[0],s[1]);
}
```

***what's wrong with my code?***
*I could run it smoothly on Visual Basic C++,but on the platform it implies that Line 58: conflicting types for 'main',i don't know what happened.*

Comment: There is no line 58 here.

Comment: Show the **exact** error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As such there's nothing wrong in your code but there's a subtle issue.

I'm not sure if Leetcode issues should be discussed here. But the error that you're getting is clearly stated in the error message "Conflicting types for main".

You do not have to write a main() function on leetcode. The thing is that leetcode already has an implicit main() function with the signature

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
```

So when you define a second main() function with a different signature, it errors out since we now have 2 conflicting main() function declarations (one defined by leetcode and another by you).

So just remove the code for main() and simply include the twoSum() function on that platform and it will work fine.